# How to redirect vim's output to terminal?

Tags: vim

I'm currently writing a small bash script to create a pre-filled file at a specific location. To do so, my bash script call vim and execute a vim script.
In this vim script, I want to ask to the user if the location where the created file is going to be saved is the correct one. The user then enter yes or no.
To do so, I'm using this set of command:

```
call inputsave()
let name = input('Is it the correct location ? y/n')
call inputrestore()
```

this input function works fine when I'm in gvim or vim. But from a script, nothing is displayed is the terminal where I launched my bash script.

Is there a way to redirect outputs to my terminal ?

I found `:redir > {file}` but this is obviously redirecting all vim outputs to a file which not interactive.

I also managed to echo something int the terminal by using this:

```
let tmp = "!echo what I want to display"
execute tmp
unlet tmp
```

but again this is only to display something. I won't be able to enter an input

my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch tmp.txt #file used to pass argument to vim
echo "$1" >> tmp.txt #append argument to the end of the txt file
vim -e tmp.txt <create_new_file.vim #launch vim and execute the scrip inside create_new_file.vim
rm tmp.txt
echo "new file created"
```

the `create_new_file.vim` basically just call my function `CreateFile(_name)` located in my `.vimrc`. This is this function who call `inputsave()`, `input()` and `inputrestore()`.

Comment: Do you use the vim script to fill the file or just to ask the user, if the location is correct and save it there?

Comment: the vim script do everything. the bash script is just there to start vim. I know it can be a bit odd but the reason is: I use vim and it is convenient to just write my command to create a new prefilled file. But I also have some colleague who don't (know how to) use vim and are interested in that feature. So basically, the bash script is a wrapper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're feeding commands directly into Vim via standard input; this way, Vim has no way to interact with you (the user), and this use of Vim is atypical and therefore discouraged.

### Alternatives

Unless you really need special Vim capabilities, you're probably better off using *non-interactive tools* like `sed`, `awk`, or Perl / Python / Ruby / *your favorite scripting language here*.

That said, you can use Vim non-interactively:

### Full Automation

For more advanced processing involving multiple windows, and real automation of Vim (where you might interact with the user or leave Vim running to let the user take over), use:

```
vim -N -u NONE -n -c "set nomore" -S "create_new_file.vim" tmp.txt
```

This should allow you to interact with Vim while following a script of commands.

Here's a summary of the used (or useful) arguments:

```
-N -u NONE        Do not load vimrc and plugins, alternatively:
--noplugin        Do not load plugins.
-n                No swapfile.
-i NONE           Ignore the |viminfo| file (to avoid disturbing the
                  user's settings).
-es               Ex mode + silent batch mode -s-ex
                  Attention: Must be given in that order!
-S ...            Source script.
-c 'set nomore'   Suppress the more-prompt when the screen is filled
                  with messages or output to avoid blocking.
```

Comment: thanks, this command works fine :) 
(with small typo. " is missing at beginning of source script's name)